# Google Earth: How to show a location in google earth after the page loads

Tags: google-maps, google-earth

I have used the sample code from the following URL.
http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/geocoder.html

I would like to show the location after the page loads. I am new to google earth.

Right now, I have removed the location form and called the buttonClick function under the initCB method. It did not works.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have either to pass the city to the geocoder in the code or to get the latitude/longitude before and insert it in the code.

-1. First option

The example use Google Maps v.2 API, while now you have available v.3 here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

```
var address = "Los Angeles";
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    point = results[0].geometry.location;
    alert(point);//this is to see the lat long values
    var lookAt = ge.createLookAt('');
    lookAt.set(point.y, point.x, 10, ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND, 
           0, 60, 20000);
ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);

  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
```

-2. Second option

```
var lookAt = ge.createLookAt('');
lookAt.set(50.5, -79.5, 10, ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND, 
           0, 60, 20000);
ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);
```

where 50.5 should be the latitude and -79.5 should be the longitude.

Hope it helps!

Cheers,
Mihai